# make foreach into json array

Tags: php, json

I'm a little confused, and I need help.

I have a foreach loop in my code below. I need to put the foreach loop into the `$data = array('image' => $final_image);`

How can i put foreach loop in array ? Anyone can help me please.

```
$getImages = isset($GetNewMessageU['imageid']) ? $GetNewMessageU['imageid'] : NULL;
$ExploreImage = explode(",", $getImages);
$CountExplodes=count($ExploreImage); 
 foreach($ExploreImage as $a) { 
     $newdata=$Post->Post_GetUploadChatImageID($a);  
     if($newdata){ 
          $final_image=$base_url."uploads/images/".$newdata['uploaded_image'];  
     } 
     echo $final_image;
 } 
 if($GetNewMessageU){
    $json = array();
    $data = array(  
       'image' => $final_image, 
    ); 
     $result =  json_encode( $data );   
   echo preg_replace('/,\s*"[^"]+":null|"[^"]+":null,?/', '', $result); 
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you want to create an array of the final images?

Comment: @JasonK Yes i want to create an array for final_images

Answer (score 1):

```
$getImages = isset($GetNewMessageU['imageid']) ? $GetNewMessageU['imageid'] : NULL;
$ExploreImage = explode(",", $getImages);
$CountExplodes=count($ExploreImage);

// Create an array to store final images

$final_images = [];

foreach($ExploreImage as $a) {
    $newdata=$Post->Post_GetUploadChatImageID($a);
    if($newdata){
        $final_image=$base_url."uploads/images/".$newdata['uploaded_image'];
        // Save the image if its new data.
        $final_images[]= $final_image;
    }


}
if($GetNewMessageU){
    $json = array();
    $data = array(
        'image' => $final_images, // We pass the final images array
    );
    $result =  json_encode( $data );
    echo preg_replace('/,\s*"[^"]+":null|"[^"]+":null,?/', '', $result);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is working fine but there is a problem. It is repeats the last item. Like `1,2,2,` there is just one 2 but it is repeating 2.

Answer (score 0):

Made things a bit more verbose.

First define the array.
Then in the if statement add element to the array.

```
$getImages = isset($GetNewMessageU['imageid']) ? $GetNewMessageU['imageid'] : NULL;
$ExploreImage = explode(",", $getImages);
$CountExplodes=count($ExploreImage); 
$final_images = array();                    // Define object as array
foreach($ExploreImage as $a) { 
  $newdata=$Post->Post_GetUploadChatImageID($a);  
    if($newdata){ 
      $final_image=$base_url."uploads/images/".$newdata['uploaded_image'];
      $final_images[] = array('image' => $final_image); // Will create new array item
    } 
    echo $final_image;
} 
if($GetNewMessageU){
  $json = array();
  $data = array(  
   'image' => $final_image, 
  ); 
  $result =  json_encode( $data );   
  echo preg_replace('/,\s*"[^"]+":null|"[^"]+":null,?/', '', $result); 
}
```

Comment: why after the echo statement. I want to print `'image' => $final_image` in `echo`.

Comment: please look at this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/mc8cwk i have two image but it is showin just one link for image

Comment: Is that's whats being sent to the server?

Comment: yes. The screenshot is from chrome developer console. It should be show two image link in array but your answer showing one image link. Because there is exploded two image id.

Comment: I would do a dump on the $ExploreImage to make sure that has multiple records.